# Content of one textarea copied to another textarea of different pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have two pages `index.php` and `search.php`, both have a search box. If the user enters the name to be searched in the `index.php` Textarea and clicks on submit button the content of the Textarea should be loaded in the `search.php` page.

index.php

```
 <form action="search.php" method="post">
     <div>
          <input type="text" name="query_data" placeholder="Who would you like to find today?">
     </div>
     <div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH"></input>
     </div>
</form>
```

search.php

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder= <?php echo $_POST["query_data"]; ?> >
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH" onclick="func()"</input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the name searched in the `index.php` page to be the **placeholder** in the `search.php` page.
The user would have to click on the search button of the `search.php` page to load the function `func()` and get the answers.
This code is wrong and is not working. It is giving an error that the *query is undefined*. Please Help! Thanks a lot!

I have added the Javascript file also. It has Ajax and is getting the right result when used on the search.php page.
The problem is not with the Javascript though!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
  var tosearch=document.getElementById("search").value;
  if(tosearch==="")
    print("<center><b>Nothing To Search For!!</b></center>");
  else
    {$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'page2.php',
      data: {'tosearch' : tosearch},
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (result) {
            print(result);
          }
        });
    }
}
function print(result){
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=result;
}
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST) to see if you can access the post values. The values will not be accessible if you refresh the page. Only if upon submit of index.php

Comment: @JPickup This code of `index.php` is taking me to the search.php file but is not displaying anything.

Comment: I think your ajax call is complicating things. PHP will post the data to search.php without using ajax.

Comment: The ajax is nowhere related to my `index.php` page It is the content of the `search.php` page and is working only when the submit button of the `search.php` page is clicked. A function by the name `func()` is being invoked which is taking the data to `page2.php` which is entirely different.

I would like to point out that the ajax and the `search.php` page is working fine. When I enter data into the Textarea of the `search.php` page the desired answer is seen.

**I want the data entered in the Textarea of the `index.php` page in the Textarea of the `search.php` page.**

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe missing the qoute try this:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="<?php echo $_POST["query"]; ?>" >
```

Comment: Already Tried, it is not working too!

The error is:
`Notice: Undefined index: query in search.php on line .... Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0007257136{main}( )..\search.php:0 ">`

Answer (score 0):

i think you page is refresh and the post value is erase 
try this

```
<div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder= <?php echo $_POST["query"]; ?> >
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="SEARCH" onclick="func()"</input>
</div>
```

you have to specifie input type button

Comment: It is still not working!
The problem is not with the submit button.

Comment: I have added the javascript code and the error is that the query is undefined  that is retrieved from the index.php page.

Comment: @Krishna i think query is reserved keywork you have try a different name and test you code.

Comment: I had my expectations that it would not have been the case but still, I have tried and the problem has persisted! Nevertheless, I have changed the code.

Comment: @krishna i think error seems different you can try. This code place at top of search.php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_error');